# PHP preg_replace/preg_match vs PHP str_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

Can anyone give me a quick summary of the differences please?

To my mind, are they both doing the same thing?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`str_replace` replaces a specific occurrence of a string, for instance "foo" will only match and replace that: "foo". `preg_replace` will do regular expression matching, for instance "/f.{2}/" will match and replace "foo", but also "fey", "fir", "fox", "f12", etc.

[EDIT]

See for yourself:

```
$string = "foo fighters";
$str_replace = str_replace('foo','bar',$string);
$preg_replace = preg_replace('/f.{2}/','bar',$string);
echo 'str_replace: ' . $str_replace . ', preg_replace: ' . $preg_replace;
```

The output is:

> str_replace: bar fighters, preg_replace: bar barhters

:)

Comment: Hmm, not really seeing a preg_replace advantage, seems a little hit'n'miss!

Comment: You didn't ask about advantages, but rather the difference between the two :D

Answer (score 21):

`str_replace` will just replace a fixed string with another fixed string, and it will be much faster.

The regular expression functions allow you to search for and replace with a *non-fixed* pattern called a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). There are many "flavors" of regular expression which are mostly similar but have certain details differ; the one we are talking about here is Perl Compatible Regular Expressions ([PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php)).

If they look the same to you, then you should use `str_replace`.

Comment: well it is nice for dynamic searches in patterns you dont know, but if you know the pattern (even if during runtime) you can create the button right then and do str_ unless you want different parts to be catched at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

`str_replace` searches for pure text occurences while `preg_replace` for patterns.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested by myself, but probably worth of testing. But according to some sources `preg_replace` is 2x faster on **PHP 7** and above.

See more here: [preg_replace vs string_replace](https://nabtron.com/preg_replace-vs-str_replace/).