# Escaping certain characters doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, string, escaping

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I couldn't find the answer through search.

Here's my code

`str_replace([' ',-,\(,\),\*,-,\|,\/], '', $params['telephone']), '0'`

and that works.  What I want it to be is:

`str_replace([' ',-,\(,\),/,|,\*,-,\#,\], '', $params['telephone']), '0'`

As soon as I add in `#` or `\` it fails, and escaping them doesn't seem to work.  Is there a different way to escape them?

And although it seemingly works, it does not seem to replace the initial space.  Could that be the root of my problem?

Comment: How can the first line work? Only 1 of the search strings (the space) is quoted. Is this your real code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove a space, `-`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `-`, `|`, `/` and also `\` and `#` symbols from the string.

You need to pass an array of these chars to [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$arr = [ '-', '(', ')', '*', '-', '|', '/', '\\', '#'];
$result = str_replace($arr, '', $s);
```

Or, you may use a regex with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like this:

```
$res = preg_replace('~[- ()*|/\\\\#]~', '', $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/VXfpCK).

**Regex details**:

- `~` is a regex delimiter, required by all `preg_` functions
- `-` must be put at the start/end of the character class, or escaped if placed anywhere else, to match literal `-`
- `\` symbol must be matched with 2 literal `\`s, and that means one needs 4 backslashes to match a single literal backslash
- Inside a character class, `*`, `(`, `)`, `|` (and `+`, `?`, `.`, too) lose there special status and do not need to be escaped
- If you work with Unicode strings, add `u` modifier after the last `~` regex delimiter: `'~[- ()*|/\\\\#]~u'`.

**[The difference between string replace and preg replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245513/php-preg-replace-preg-match-vs-php-str-replace)**

`str_replace` replaces a specific occurrence of a literal string, for instance `foo` will only match and replace that: `foo`.

`preg_replace` will perform replacements using a regular expression, for instance `/f.{2}/` will match and replace `foo`, but also `fey`, `fir`, `fox`, `f12`, `f )` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_replace()!

You can delete specific Characters this way

```
$foo = preg_replace('/[yourcharacters]/', '', $foo);
```

And you can also do it the other Way around (deleting all but the determined Characters) by adding a ^ (see Regex-Tables).

```
$foo = preg_replace('/[^theonlyallowedcharacters]/', '', $foo);
```

Comment: Thank you, useful advice on the only allow part.  Perhaps I would be better off doing this as I only want numbers.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Can you help me to understand why have you added `/` before and after when the other answer has `~`?

Comment: You're welcome! It just indicates the Begin and The End of the Regex. If you only want Numbers and you use Regex to filter the Input, you can use /[^0-9]/. Happy Programming :)

Comment: But wait.  If `/` means the start/end of a regex then what does `~` do?  It appears the same in the other answer.  It is referred to as a delimiter.  Does this mean I could use multiple regexes by using `~`?

Comment: It is also just a Delimiter in this Context!

Comment: And no, you can no use multiple Regexes this way.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **add \ for special characters** for your regular expression.

**Please, replace with this code,**

```
 ['',\(,\),\/,\|,\*,-,\#,\\]
```

**Instead of yours,**

```
[' ',-,\(,\),/,|,\*,-,\#,\]
```

I hope it may helpful.

Comment: I think this is incorrect, I had used special characters and removed the ones that were not necessary by trial and error and by using PHP Storm to validate.  Also I needed that space in there :)